# split Window "Radio Button Test" into Window, Radio Button Test

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter, quotations

I am having trouble parsing an input file properly in Java.

Input file:

`Window "Radio Buttons"  (300, 200)`

I need to split it into:

```
Window

"

Radio Buttons

"

(

300

,

200

)
```

I am currently using `line.split("\\s")` which is giving me:

```
Window

"Radio

Button"

(300,

200)
```

I just don't know what delimiter or regex to use.

Comment: Use a regular expression that splits on the characters `"(,)`. For background check out [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and you can play around in a sandbox [here](http://www.regexr.com/).

Comment: Start by identifying what it is `String#startsWith`, based on that, decide how to parse its properties

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox link, @bcattle. I still can't seem to figure out the expression that splits according to what I need.